# Non-commutative fractions

Tags: symbols, fractions

There are symbols for non-commutative fractions? I know `\holter` and `\polter` (see [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/holtpolt)), but they are very ugly (lateral lines are too long for my taste)

Edit:
By non-comutative fraction I mean a division in non-commutative contest; for example in a non-commutative multiplicative group, we have two possible division, namely `ab^{-1}` and  `b^{-1}a`, hence, in order to distinguish them, we cannot write `\frac ab`, but `\holter ab` or `\polter ab`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you point to where we can find `\holter` and `\polter`?

Comment: A mathematical question : what are non-commutative fractions ?

Comment: I find \holter and \polter here http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf at page 63

Comment: @FabioLucchini I'd stick to `ab^{-1}` and `a^{-1}b`. But that's me.

Comment: For more complicated expressions can be useful a fractional notation. I'm looking for a more elegant symbol than \holter and \polter.

Comment: I would say there's quite a *bit* wrong with the settings of `\holter` and `\polter`; it uses the `array` environment and `\multicolumn` to do its job and the vertical spacing is cramped. If this notation is actually ever used, it needs a better implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are provided settable versions of `\holter` and `\polter`.  The settable parameters include `\strutheight`, the height (+depth) of the strut, `\strutdepth`, the depth of the strut, `\strutpad`, the extra length added to the horizontal rule relative to the longest argument, and `\strutrule`, the thickness of the rule lines.  I made the rule heights a fixed length, but if you would prefer the `\strutheight` and `\strutdepth` to be matched to the argument heights and depths, that could be done, as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newlength\strutrule
%HERE ARE YOUR SETTABLE PARAMETERS
\def\strutheight{2.7ex}
\def\strutdepth{-.8ex}
\def\strutpad{2pt}
\setlength\strutrule{.1ex}
%
% From egreg's answer at 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145306/cramped-style-again-working-simple-code
\def\cramped#1{%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace\radical0{#1}
}
\def\xolterstrut{\rule[\strutdepth]{\strutrule}{\strutheight}}
\newlength\xolterlen
\newcommand\holter[2]{%
  \setlength\xolterlen{\maxof{\widthof{$#1$}}{\widthof{$#2$}}}%
  \addtolength\xolterlen{\strutpad}%
  \stackon[-.8\strutrule]{%
    \stackanchor[-.8\strutrule]{\rule{\xolterlen}{\strutrule}}{%
      \makebox[\xolterlen]{$\cramped{#2}$}\xolterstrut}%
  }{\xolterstrut\makebox[\xolterlen]{$#1$}}%
}
\newcommand\polter[2]{%
  \setlength\xolterlen{\maxof{\widthof{$#1$}}{\widthof{$#2$}}}%
  \addtolength\xolterlen{\strutpad}%
  \stackon[-.8\strutrule]{%
    \stackanchor[-.8\strutrule]{\rule{\xolterlen}{\strutrule}}{%
      \xolterstrut\makebox[\xolterlen]{$\cramped{#2}$}}%
  }{\makebox[\xolterlen]{$#1$}\xolterstrut}%
}
\begin{document}
$x = \holter{abcg}{deg}$,
$y = \polter{abcg}{deg^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that elegance is out of the question, with symbols like those.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\holter}[2]{%
  \mathinner{
    \sbox0{$\textstyle\,\cramped{#2}\,$}%
    \sbox2{\copy0\vrule height\ht\strutbox}
    \raise\dimexpr-\ht2-\dp2-2pt+\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax\vbox{
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{%
        ##\cr
        \vrule\hfil$\textstyle\,#1\,\mathstrut$\hfil\cr
        \vrule height 1pt\hfil\cr
        \noalign{\hrule}
        \hfil\vrule height1pt\cr
        \hfil\box0\hfil\vrule height\ht\strutbox\cr
        \hfil\vrule height1pt\cr
      }
    }%
  }
}

\newcommand{\polter}[2]{%
  \mathinner{
    \sbox0{$\textstyle\,\cramped{#2}\,$}%
    \sbox2{\copy0\vrule height\ht\strutbox}
    \raise\dimexpr-\ht2-\dp2-2pt+\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax\vbox{
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{%
        ##\cr
        \hfil$\textstyle\,#1\,\mathstrut$\hfil\vrule\cr
        \hfil\vrule height1pt\cr
        \noalign{\hrule}
        \vrule height1pt\hfil\cr
        \vrule height\ht\strutbox\hfil\box0\hfil\cr
        \vrule height1pt\hfil\cr
      }
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{g}{g}\holter{a}{b}\holter{g}{g}\quad\polter{a}{b}\quad\holter{x}{y^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

The fraction is meant to show that the fraction line is vertically placed at the correct position.

[image]