# \bigl( \bigr) in inline mode and in align environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align

The following, I believe, is a strange behavior of `\bigl(<math content>\bigr)` in inline math mode and in the align environment. Consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
Consider having an exponential expression raised to another power; for instance, $\bigl(a^2\bigr)^4$. Using the definition of $a^n$,
    \begin{align*}
    \bigl(a^2\bigr)^4 &= \bigl(a^2\bigr)\bigl(a^2\bigr)\bigl(a^2\bigr)\bigl(a^2\bigr) && \text{Here the base is $\bigl(a^2\bigr)$}\\
    &=\underbrace{(a\cdot a)(a \cdot a)(a \cdot a)(a \cdot a)}_{\text{$2 \cdot 4$ or 8  factors}}\\
    &=a^8
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The difference is obvious if you zoom in. For example:

[image][image]

Note the parenthesis are of different heights. I suppose its due to the definition of the commands `\bigl` and `\bigr`. Can any one shed some insight into the matter. I know several users here prefer using the above rather than `\left` to `\right` so am refraining from these commands. I would also like a fix to the size of the parenthesis.

### EDIT

It seems that the exponent, "superscript", is the one to blame here for its behaviour in the modes `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle`.

Comment: I don't see the “obvious difference”, the right one is just a little bit down, isn't it? [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146639/21930) you can see the definition of `\big`. By the way, what role does `\left` and `\right` play here?

Comment: I think it has something to do with "cramped" mathstyles.

Comment: @Manuel That's the difference. It's not that obvious but weird.

Comment: See for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145306/cramped-style-again-working-simple-code regarding cramped styles or else http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154474/how-to-prevent-superscripts-from-moving-under-sqrt/154480#154480

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - The present case is actually not related to cramped vs uncramped setting of superscripts within one and the same math style, say `\textstyle`; rather, it arises because the amount by which the superscript is raised above the baseline is greater when `\displaystyle` is in effect (as is the case in an `align` environment) than when `\textstyle` is in effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brackets are the same size, but the superscripts 2 and 4 are lower in inline math than in display style

Comment: @azetina you only need it once per alignment cell not in each factor, you could locally do  \let\displaystyle\relax if you wanted an alignment in textstyle